# Move cronjobs from deleted users to new user?

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I deleted a user and created a new one.
The cronjobs of the deleted user are still running.

How can I "move" them to the new user?

Answer (score 3):

On Raspbian Stretch you normally maintain cronjobs with `crontab` and `man crontab` says: "each user can have their own crontab, and though these are files in /var/spool/cron/crontabs". If you delete an user by `sudo deluser [username]`, you do not delete the crontab of this user. Run `sudo ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs` and you'll see a file named like the (deleted) username. You can work with this file like you want.